# ナビゲーションバー上でのツールチップ表示の日本語がおかしい

Tags: バグ, 完了

ナビゲーションバーの StackExchange の文字の上にカーソルを置いてツールチップの表示をさせると

「132つの全ての...」

となっていて、日本語がオカシイです。

Answer (score 1):

開発者に下記の改正を頼みます。適用まではしばらくお待ちください。

> 133個の全てのStack Exchangeサイトのリスト

Comment: ポイントは、日本語だと、10以上の数字には「つ」をつけないところです。「１つの全ての」〜「９つの全ての」は正しいですが「10つの全ての」以降「132つの全ての」は正しくありません。たとえば、「132個の全ての」が正しいです。

なので、提案、というより、数値表記のバグだと思うのですが、提案に相当しますでしょうか。

Comment: @shigeya なるほど、だから「133の全てのStack Exchangeサイトのリスト」でいいですね？

Comment: <数>の、と言う表記は、最近よくつかわれていますが（英語から日本語へ翻訳されたサイトで）、日本語としては少し不自然です。上の例よりは随分良いとはおもいますけれども。できれば、【133個の】と「個」を補った方が少しマシじゃないかと思います。